# Angularstrap datapicker There is an "easy" way to remove day name

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap, datapicker

[image]

I just want to remove this tr, there is no particular css selector by default
i wonder if there is an custom way to remove it

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: there is no particular code, is the same example of angular strap documentation:
http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers

Comment: I'm sure there's a selector that would remove it. Maybe `.datepicker table tr:nth-child(1)' or something like that. Try something, then if you have trouble, update your question with your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any specific class on this "tr".

What you can do is open it in chrome dev tools by right clicking on the element and selecting inspect, then right click on "**tr**" and then click copy and then Copy Selector. This is the selector which you can now use in CSS.

Have an ID or class on datePicker head element though. That will help shorten the selector path.

For one on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker the selector will be **#datepicker > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-md-6.show-grid > div > div > div > div > div > table > thead > tr:nth-child(2)**

Then hide it using CSS.

Comment: got it!:

thead{      
tr:last-child{
        display:none;
        visibility: hidden;      
      };

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
tr.ng-binding.ng-scope {
    display: none;
}
```

([plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TjlwDQICxJZLhKwGFqbn?p=preview))